# Deep learning with Tensorflow: personalized training loop that learn with one element at a time

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to use batch with element of different size, so i try to create a personalized training loop, the main idea is to start from the one supplied from keras:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in enumerate(train_dataset):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            logits = model(x_batch_train, training=True)  
            loss_value = loss_fn(y_batch_train, logits)
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

and add a cicle over the batch size, in this way i can train the network one element a time, and update the weight only after every element of the batch pass trough the newtork. Something like:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for training in range(trainingsize):
       for batch in range(batchsize):
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
               logits = model(x, training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch
               loss_value = loss_fn(, logits)
            grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
     optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

where x and y are a single element of the batch.

But i notice that in this way i consider only the last batch ( because grads is ovewritten).

How can i manage this? I don't know how to "merge" different grads.

Also one curiosity: i thought that the variable create with "with" statements are valid only inside the statement, so how is it possible that using it outside works?

UPDATE

---

I tried SoheilStar's solution, but tape.gradient return a vector [None, None, None, None] and on "apply_gradients" it said " No gradients provided for any variable: ['conv1d/kernel:0', 'conv1d/bias:0', 'dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0']."

I don't know how to debug in this case to find the problem

There is the main part of the code i use:

```
optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam( learning_rate=0.001,name="Adam")
loss_fn = keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(2, ksize, activation='relu', input_shape=ishape))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D(data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))


for epoch in range(epochsize):
    batchp=1
    for k in range(trainingsize):
        loss_value = tf.constant(0.)
        mini_batch_losses=[]
        for s in range(batchsize):
            X_train, y_train = loadvalue(batchp) #caricamento elementi
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                logits = model(X_train , training=True)
                loss_value = loss_fn(y_train, logits)
            mini_batch_losses.append(loss_value)
            batchp += 1
        loss_avg = tf.reduce_mean(mini_batch_losses)
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_avg, model.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

UPDATE 2:
I notice that if i change the training cicle in this way, it works but i don't understand why and if it is correct:

```
for epoch in range(epochsize):
    batchp=1
    for k in range(trainingsize):
        loss_value = tf.constant(0.)
        mini_batch_losses=[]
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            for s in range(batchsize):
                X_train, y_train = loadvalue(batchp)
                logits = model(X_train , training=True)
                tape.watch(X_train)
                loss_value = loss_fn(y_train, logits)
            mini_batch_losses.append(loss_value)
            batchp += 1
            loss_avg = tf.reduce_mean(mini_batch_losses)
        grads = tape.gradient(loss_avg, model.trainable_weights)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grads variable only contains the gradients of variables. to apply them you need to move the optimizer inside the last For loop. but why not writing a normal training loop and then set the batch_size to one?

====== Update

you can calculate the loss for each sample in the last For loop and then do a reduce_mean to calculate the mean of loss and then calculate the grads. code updated.

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for training in range(trainingsize):
       mini_batch_losses = []
       for batch in range(batchsize):
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
               logits = model(x, training=True)  # Logits for this minibatch
               loss_value = loss_fn(y_true, logits)
            mini_batch_losses.append(loss_value)
       loss_avg = tf.reduce_mean(mini_batch_losses)
       grads = tape.gradient(loss_avg , model.trainable_weights)
       optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
```

Comment: (Thanks for the reply!)

Because i don't want to update it after every element. The idea is to use the batch, but i have element of the batch of different size, and for some reason i don't want to do something like zero padding

Comment: Yes! Like this it can work. But i have just one question: i don't know how GradientTape works in detail,is a problem that the GradientTape is called different time before calculate the gradient?

Comment: if you are familiar with tf graph execution, in the list of loss_avg you just know what is the graph of loss of each sample. in tape gradient, gradient happened with respect to model vars. after each grad, it will calculate the mean of all grads. above code is equal to calculate the grad for each batch and then do the mean and then pass it to the optimizer. try to write it on paper and do it from end to start.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i'm starting to read about the graph and now is more clear..so i try to apply your solution but something doesn't work... can you help me? (i've updated the question)